# "Module not found" when importing a Python package within a plpython3u procedure

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, macos, plpython

I am using a `plpython3` stored function, on a `postgres` database on `MacOS` (installed with standard Enterprise DB package).

I can import standard python packages such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(x double precision)
RETURNS double precision
LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $$
import math
...
$$
```

I cannot, however import packages I have installed on the regular python3 directory on my machine, which is defined by brew:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

So `import foo` would not work even though it would work in the regular python3 environment.

Would it be possible that the `PostgreSQL` server is not using the same python3 environment as me when running `plpython3u`? (perhaps it is using the python3 interpreter which is standard issue on `MacOS` etc.) How can I check on that and how could I correct the configuration, in the event?

And indeed, I created a stored function `get_py` that does the following:

```
import os
return os.popen('which python').read()
```

And it returned:

```
> select get_py()
+-----------------+
| get_py          |
|-----------------|
| /usr/bin/python |
+-----------------+
```

(and nothing for `which python3`). Which seems to demonstrate that it is not using the interpreter I want!

How do I change this?

#### Config info

- `PostgreSQL 11.5` on `x86_64-apple-darwin`, compiled by Apple LLVM version 6.0
- I am not using any `virtualenv` here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other environment variables like `PGDATA` in a shell script (pg_service.sh), set the `PYTHONPATH='/path/to/python:/path/to/your/module'`

E.g. cat /Users/postgres/pg_service.sh

```
export PGDATABASE=postgres
export PGUSER=postgres
export PGPORT=5432
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/11/bin:$PATH
export PGLOCALEDIR=/Library/PostgreSQL/11/share/locale
export PYTHONUSERBASE=/Users/postgres/packaging_tutorial
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/edb/languagepack-11/Python-3.6:$PYTHONUSERBASE
pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/11/data -l /Users/postgres/logfile $1
```

Start the server:

```
> sudo -u postgres /Users/postgres/pg_service.sh start
waiting for server to start.... done
server started
```

`/Users/postgres/packaging_tutorial/example_pkg/__init__.py`:

```
def retpy3():
    return 7/5
```

pg function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expy3()
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $$
import example_pkg
return example_pkg.retpy3()
$$;
```

Output

```
psql  -c 'select * from expy3()';
 expy3
--------
 1.4
```

Comment: Thanks: I am on Mac and I do see `PYTHONPATH=/Library/edb/languagepack-11/Python-3.6`. What is it? Postgres implementation of Python? (plpython3u?)

Comment: [From the docs](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/user-guides/language-pack-guide/11/EDB_Postgres_Language_Pack_Guide.1.02.html#) Language pack installers contain supported languages that may be used with EDB Postgres Advanced Server and EnterpriseDB PostgreSQL database installers. The language pack installer allows you to install Perl, TCL/TK, and Python without installing supporting software from third party vendors.
Python version 3.6.8

Comment: I did the above procedure (I had to start with: `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/11/data   start`). Unfortunately, when attempting trying to run the `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`, I get: `could not access file "$libdir/plpython3": No such file or directory` (in other words, plpython3 seems now broken?) What did I do incorrectly? Note: `echo $PYTHONPATH` gives back: `/Library/edb/languagepack-11/Python-3.6:/my/path/hello.py`

Comment: Yes, I was able to replicate that. That error means the PYTHONPATH variable was not available for the pg_ctl command. I've edited the answer to include the script and sudo command to start the server.

Comment: Is the ability to dictate the interpreter used via PYTHONPATH something only available in the Enterprise DB port of postgre, or should that work in say, the CentOS 7 RPM for postgre?

Comment: @refriedjello it will work in CentOS 7 rpm for postgres too https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython-envar.html