# How to install a Python package on Linux so that it is found by the already working PostgreSQL 13 plpython3u extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, postgresql, ubuntu

#### Spin-off:

I have tried to catch the idea of [“Module not found” when importing a Python package within a plpython3u procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774168/module-not-found-when-importing-a-python-package-within-a-plpython3u-procedure), I did not know how to use the accepted answer there to make it run on Linux. Normally, this here should be a duplicate, but if there is a difference with with MacOS in the used paths, it might be good for a new question.

#### Installation of PostgreSQL 13

I am on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04). I installed with the commands of the official PostgreSQL Downloads page from the [PostgreSQL Apt Repository for Ubuntu](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).

```
# Create the file repository configuration:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

# Import the repository signing key:
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# Update the package lists:
sudo apt-get update

# Install the latest version of PostgreSQL.
# If you want a specific version, use 'postgresql-12' or similar instead of 'postgresql':
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
```

This gave me PostgreSQL 13.

#### Installation of the right plpython3u

I installed plpython3u with commands from [PostgreSQL: how to install plpythonu extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150830/11154841):

```
sudo apt-cache search ".*plpython3.*"
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython3-13
```

Because I am on WSL, I start the service with:

```
service postgresql start
```

Change role and run psql:

```
sudo su postgres
psql
```

#### PostgreSQL with plpython3u installation and tests without imported packages

Checking the Python version directly as a stored procedure in postgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_version()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$
    import sys
    return sys.version
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

Output:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Test:

```
postgres=# SELECT return_version();
              return_version
------------------------------------------
 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) +
 [GCC 9.4.0]
(1 row)
```

shows that for "PostgreSQL 13", **"Python 3.8.10"** gets installed.

And this is exactly the one to be found on Linux. If I just enter a Python version that I do not have, like `3.7`:

```
python3.7
```

I get the overview:

```
Command 'python3.7' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3.8' from deb python3.8 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)
  command 'python3.9' from deb python3.9 (3.9.5-3~20.04.1)
  command 'python2.7' from deb python2.7 (2.7.18-1~20.04.1)
```

Confirming that there are no two parallel installations of Python `3.8` installed, it is clear that the Linux `3.8.10` is the used version for plpython3u in PostgreSQL.

#### plpython3u stored procedure tests with imported packages

I tried a function that imports packages, taken from [Kmeans in PostgreSQL in a nutshell](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/machine-learning-in-postgresql-part-1-kmeans-clustering/):

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION kmeans(input_table text, columns text[], clus_num int) RETURNS bytea AS
 
$$
 
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from pickle import dumps
 
all_columns = ",".join(columns)
if all_columns == "":
    all_columns = "*"
 
rv = plpy.execute('SELECT %s FROM %s;' % (all_columns, plpy.quote_ident(input_table)))
 
frame = []
 
for i in rv:
    frame.append(i)
df = DataFrame(frame).astype('float')
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=clus_num, random_state=0).fit(df._get_numeric_data())
return dumps(kmeans)
 
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

Output:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Test throws the error:

```
postgres=# SELECT kmeans('my_table', ARRAY['col1', 'col2'],3);
ERROR:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "kmeans", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
PL/Python function "kmeans"
```

Then, I installed pandas in Python `3.8`:

```
python3.8 -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.3.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 11.5 MB 6.0 MB/s
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7.3
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 247 kB 4.7 MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.17.3
  Downloading numpy-1.21.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 15.8 MB 131 kB/s
Collecting pytz>=2017.3
  Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 510 kB 5.7 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.14.0)
Installing collected packages: python-dateutil, numpy, pytz, pandas
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.8 are installed in '/home/my_user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed numpy-1.21.2 pandas-1.3.2 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2021.1
```

And pandas is now stored at:

```
python3.8 -m pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.3.2
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: The Pandas Development Team
Author-email: pandas-dev@python.org
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pytz
Required-by:
```

But the test still throws the same error:

```
postgres=# SELECT kmeans('my_table', ARRAY['col1', 'col2'],3);
ERROR:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "kmeans", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
PL/Python function "kmeans"
```

#### Question

How to install pandas (or any other package I need) so that it is found by the PostgreSQL 13 plpython3u extension on Linux?

#### PS: probably not needed side notes

##### Probably not needed: Use "which" in a plpython3u stored procedure to check Python

The spun-off question had another version test in it, but that was not showing anything from inside the extension, the commands are just the same as in the normal bash. Therefore, the value of the following is reduced to just a random test of the a plpython3u function. I add this only because you should never be 100 % sure. To me, it is clear that this does not say anything about the Python version that is actually used by plpython3u.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_py()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$
    import os
    return os.popen('which python3').read()
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

Output:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Test:

```
SELECT get_py();
      get_py
------------------
 /usr/bin/python3+

(1 row)
```

And the same with `'which python3.8'`:

```
select get_py();
       get_py
--------------------
 /usr/bin/python3.8+

(1 row)
```

##### Probably not needed: use make and a default Python version to install

Perhaps the default version of Python must be changed somewhere before installation? This is just a very vague guess from [an installation using make, with Python settings in /etc/make.conf](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/postgresql-plpython3u.67295/), here is the code that is used there (question from 2018):

Changing `/etc/make.conf` to

```
DEFAULT_VERSIONS+= python=3.6
```

It is said that this ran through and installed plpython3u (I have not tested this):

```
root@db% cd /usr/ports/databases/posgresql10-plpython
root@db% make fetch
root@db% make extract
root@db% cd /usr/ports/databases/postgresql10-plpython/work/postgresql-10.5
root@db% ./configure PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 --with-python --with-libraries=/usr/local/lib --with-includes=/usr/local/include/
root@db% cd /usr/ports/databases/posgresql10-plpython
root@db% make install
```

Comment: Not clear to me how you actually installed the `plpython3u` extension? Also how did you install Postgres and from what repo?  Are you using any sort of containers? I just saw this `Location: /home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`. The package is being installed as package local to the user and the extension is looking for a system package as the server is running as system service.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added the installation steps. How to install the packages as system packages instead?

Comment: I would have thought `python3.8 -m pip install pandas` would have installed to the system directory, as I thought you needed to use `--user` to get it to install to your home directory.  I would run `python3.8 -m pip config list` to see if there a configuration variable being set.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Perhaps this happens because I am on WSL2. And `python3.8 -m pip config list` returns nothing. Which path would be the right system path? Could it be `/lib/python3.8/site-packages` instead of `/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`?

Comment: Actually I believe it is simpler then that. I was not paying close enough attention and did not catch that, `python3.8 -m pip install pandas` was not run with sudo. A quick test on my machine shows that this causes the package to be installed to home directory. Try with `sudo python3.8 -m pip install pandas`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes. That was it. Now it is not the pandas package anymore that is said to be missing :)! I somehow had learnt that using sudo with pip is not recommeneded. That was obviously a misunderstanding. Please answer.

Comment: Using `sudo` with `pip` will install to the system `site-packages`. For something like `plpython3u` that is not a bad thing as the Python launched, `return sys.version` will look there. The not recommended advice comes from development work where it is best practices to work in a `virtenv` and install to that or use your local(home) packages. Then you are not adding/overwriting/deleteing system level packages that the OS or other programs may need and may be pinned to a specific version.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - given the effort you put into this, don't you think you should make the `sudo pip install` part an answer, rather than just a comment? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that this:

`python3.8 -m pip install pandas`

installs a package(pandas in this case) to the `site-packages` in the  home directory of the user running the command, so:

`/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

The `plpython3u` extension running in Postgres is looking for the package in the system wide `site-packages`. To get the package there you need to do:

`sudo python3.8 -m pip install pandas`

Comment: Works. Not even the need to restart postgresql, psql sees the installed packages during runtime. Also checked: I do not need to uninstall the unneeded packages in the `.local` directory. I can run `python3.8 -m pip uninstall pandas`, but I do not need to, since psql will search only for the global installation anyway, and the global and the local installation are not linked.

Comment: Actually it is `plpython3u` that picks up the packages. `psql` is the Postgres client program and does not look for Python packages. It works now because a `plpython3u` function is basically a Python script that `import`('s) when it is run, so once the package was in the correct place the script could do the `import`.  Yeah, unless you do some messing around with `PYTHONPATH` local and global should remain separate.